# Why is the box for the arm tefillin called yad?

Tags: tefilin

The mitzva is to wrap the tefillin on the arm.  So, why is the box for the arm tefillin called shel yad? (I think this is universal usage.) The word for arm is only 4 letters.

Comment: יד is also used as a general term for arm. https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary%2C_%D7%99%D6%B8%D7%93?lang=bi

Comment: Because the possuk says  וּקְשַׁרְתָּ֥ם לְא֖וֹת עַל־יָדֶ֑ךָ